# Does the JavaScript event loop yield control between map iterations?

Tags: javascript

This is a bit of an elementary question, but as I learn JavaScript I'm still hazy on some of the nuances of the runtime. Specifically I'm curious how the event loop handles things like `Array.prototype.map`? Without knowing the precise implementation, I'm wondering if code can be executed between iterations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. `map` is a synchronous operation.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('run as soon as possible');
}, 0);

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(function(x) {
  console.log(x);
});
```

The event loop basically breaks down like this:

1. Run synchronous code
2. Add items to the event queue as needed
3. Finish running synchronous code
4. Check the event queue for any code that should run now
5. If async code is ready to run, start it as synchronous code and return to 1
6. If no code is ready to run, return to 4.

Comment: So say you build up an array of functions via `map`, presumably if you execute those functions on the next line `setTimeout` should fire before those functions are executed?

Comment: @maxcountryman If you run any more synchronous code directly after the map, that code will run before the function passed to setTimeout

Comment: You're saying that `setTimeout` will not execute its callback before the next line of synchronous code?